# Notification not generating when device in sleep/idle mode

Tags: android

I'm generating a notification from service class. code is here

```
SharedPreferences userPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
String defaultRingTone = "content://settings/system/notification_sound";
String alarms = userPreferences.getString("notifications_new_message_ringtone", defaultRingTone);
Uri ringToneUri = Uri.parse(alarms);
notificationBuilder.setSound(ringToneUri);
// Play default notification sound
// Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
boolean isVivbrate = userPreferences.getBoolean("notifications_new_message_vibrate", true);
notificationBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(notificationID, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Issue is that when device is in idle/sleep mode notification not generating and when I wake up device manually immediately i got all pending notifications. I'm getting this issue in android L and M. I also try to generate notification by Wake Lock and change notification priority but not found any solution.

Is there any way to resolve this issue ?